# Editting data by ADMIN

Tags: php, get, edit

I am new to PHP and working on small local webpage and database that takes user information and database stores the same user information .If i Login with ADMIN it shows all data. My requirement is that the loggined user is an admin, then he has a right to edit all the informtion of the users that i stored in the database.And this is to be done using GET method . How it will be working?

Comment: please show what you have already done and how it's implemented right now- then this community will be able to assist you with your problem. Right now you question sounds very abstract

Comment: do i need to put whole coding here.....                     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td >" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td >" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td >" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
echo "<td >" . $row['annual_i'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['has_e'] .", ".$row['has_d'] .", ".$row['has_t'] .", ".$row['has_c'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['movies'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "Edit" ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

Comment: now want this edit to work as a hyperlink so that admin can alter information

Comment: append you database with field rec_id (int, unique) and code for opening specific person details for editing would be echo "<td><a href =\"editPage.php?id=".$row['rec_id']."\">Edit</a></td>";

Comment: or if you dont want to alter DB structure, you can pass parameters in your edit link like this: <a href =\"editPage.php?firstName=".$row['fname']."&lastName=".$row['lname']."\">Edit</a>   On your editPage.php make select useing where clause with your firstName and lastName parameter on $_GET variable. But in this case you have to be sure that there is only one person with same first and last names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres some example code purely to demonstrate how to update a table using a GET method form.  The code doesn't have any kind of error checking and assumes you already know how to connect to your database (and that its MySQL).

Assuming you've landed on a page which invites you to edit data, which record you're editing is referenced by an 'id' variable on the URL which matches a numerical primary key in your database table.

```
<?php
$SQL = "SELECT myField1,myField2 FROM myTable WHERE myKeyField = '".intval($_GET['id'])."'";
$QRY = mysql_query($SQL);

$DATA = mysql_fetch_assoc($QRY);
?>

<form method='get' action='pageThatStoresData.php'>
  <input type='hidden' name='key' value='<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' />
  <input type='text' name='myField1' value="<?php echo $DATA['myField1']; ?>" /> 
  <input type='text' name='myField2' value="<?php echo $DATA['myField2']; ?>" /> 
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, this will give you a page that takes the data out of your table, displays it in a form with pre-filled values and on submit, will go to a URL like:

```
http://mydomain.com/pageThatStoresData.php?key=1&myField1=someData&myField2=someMoreData
```

In that page, you can access variables 'key', 'myField1', 'myField2' via the $_GET method.

Then you just need to update your table within that page:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE myTable 
        SET myField1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['myField1'])."',
            myField2 = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['myField1'])."
        WHERE key = '".intval($_GET['key'])."'
        ";

$QRY = mysql_query($SQL);
```

PLEASE NOTE: The code above is unsuitable for a straight copy/paste as it doesn't do any error checking etc, its purely a functional example (and typed straight in here so I apologise if there are any typos!).